# Как передать дополнительное значение в jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Есть такой код который отправляет GET запрос на php файл с введенным значением:

```
$('input[name="search-control"]').autocomplete({
    source: "/search.php",
    ...
```

В итоге получается запрос: `/search.php?term=text`

Мне нужно добавить еще одно значение, чтобы запрос был такой: `/search.php?term=text&new=value`

В идеале хотелось бы что-то вроде:

```
$('input[name="search-control"]').autocomplete({
    source: "/search.php",
    data: {
        new: 'value'
    }
    ...
```

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: А как сейчас у вас попадает в запрос эта часть `?term=text`?

Comment: @Quazimorda не знаю, видимо это по умолчанию сделано в  jquery autocomplete

Comment: Может быть тут что-то про передачу параметров https://habr.com/ru/post/74713/ ?

Comment: и почему не написать `source: '/search.php?new=value'` ?

Comment: или если значение не статичное, то  у вас всегда есть вид `source: function(){....}` где можете сами отправлять запрос на поиск и т..п с какими угодно параметрами.